# Does Sleep not have synchronization semantic?

Tags: c#, clr, memory-barriers

> java spec 17.3 Sleep and Yield
>
> It is important to note that **neither Thread.sleep nor Thread.yield have any synchronization semantics**. In particular, the compiler does not have to flush writes cached in registers out to shared memory before a call to Thread.sleep or Thread.yield, nor does the compiler have to reload values cached in registers after a call to Thread.sleep or Thread.yield.
>
> For example, in the following (broken) code fragment, assume that this.done is a nonvolatile boolean field:
>
> ```
> while (!this.done)
>     Thread.sleep(1000);
> ```
>
> The compiler is free to read the field this.done just once, and reuse the cached value in each execution of the loop. This would mean that the loop would never terminate, even if another thread changed the value of this.done.

**Question:** is it same in C#?

as we know, we can add Thread.MemoryBarrier(); to fix the issue.

```
while(this.done)
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

**Question:** But is Compiler able to identify fun() as MemoryBarrier in following case?

```
public static void fun()
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
}
while(this.done)
{
    fun();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

if it's ok, why it doesn't identify sleep as MemoryBarrier since it can't make sure whether sleep contain MemoryBarrier?

Comment: Why *should* `Sleep` have a memory barrier? There are plenty of uses of `Sleep` and not many of them are for polling a variable (there are usually better synchronization primitives available for cross-thread signaling)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever then how about my fun()? will it be identified as MemoryBarrier because compiler doesn't know its content? I just think sleep and other function should be identified as MemoryBarrier.

Comment: That's nonsense, it is the jitter that must obey the memory model.  And it certainly will not emit a barrier when it can inline the method to a few machine code instructions, that would be awful.

Comment: @HansPassant oh sorry. I'm confused. are you telling me JIT will not indentify fun as memorybarrier when fun() is in another assembly though fun inclues MemoryBarrier?

Comment: It doesn't give a hoot.  Of course it will not a remove a barrier if you explicitly coded one.  You are well on your way to shooting your leg off, thinking that skipping synchronization is okay has to be unlearned the hard way.  If you don't like the school of hard knocks then you use a ManualResetEvent/Slim.

Comment: @Vince - okay, *you* have decided that `Sleep` should have a memory barrier because you think it would be useful. But what about the infinite number of other loops that people *might* code that **should** have a memory barrier in them to be correct? Should *every* function call, then, have a memory barrier associated with it? Where do you draw the dividing line between methods that should have memory barrier effects and those that should not?

Comment: @HansPassant I have a long jounery to learn compiler. thanks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what you said is I'm confused with. if compiler identify most of methods as memorybarrier, then it lose the chance to opimize. _ReadWriteBarrier note that "In Visual C++ 2005 and later, these functions are enforced all the way up the call tree".http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e(v=vs.90).aspx so I'm thinking whether Thread.MemoryBarrier has the similar mechinism to tell caller tree the memorybarrier exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Sleep` does not explicitly claim to have any such semantic, the only safe answer is "don't rely on it having any such semantic". There are plenty of ways of safely polling a variable or checking some other token (personally I'd be tempted to look at a `Monitor.Wait(obj, timeout)`, but YMMV). You say:

> I just think sleep and other function should be identified as MemoryBarrier.

Since the `Sleep` method does not claim to do this, you cannot rely on it. It could be that the designers actively disagree with you; it could be that it never even came up for discussion (after all, that is a fairly arbitrary effect).

Comment: how about my fun()? does it act as MemoryBarrier though it's in another assembly?

Comment: @Vince there is nothign that says it *will*, so the only safe answer to that is "no, it will not"

Comment: so by your mean, the compiler has a list of MemoryBarrier-function such as Thread.MemoryBarrier, Volatile.Read and Volatile.Write and so on. it doesn't trust other function though they include MemoryBarrier internally?

Comment: @Vince the *language* compiler has very little to do with it; this is mainly JIT/CLI internals.

Comment: yes. it's JIT producing native from IL. so user should explicitly expose MemoryBarrier semantic by known MemoryBarrier-function, otherwise JIT may optimize that as MemoryBarrier doesn't exist to provide most efficient.